# Why not say סברי before the blessing on wine at a wedding ceremony?

Tags: blessing, wedding, grapes-wine

The Rema in [O Ch 174(8)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.174.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says

> ויאמר סברי רבותי ר"ל סוברים אתם לצאת בברכה זו ולא יאמר ברשות רבותי
>   (מו) וכן כל מקום שמברכין על היין משום ברכת היין שבתוך הסעודה אין
>   אומרים ברשות אלא סברי מטעם שנתבאר:
>
> (Talking about making a brocha on wine for others during a meal): and
>   he should say  סברי רבותי which means – do you agree, my masters, that
>   this blessing should serve for you? And he should not say  ברשות רבותי
>   and similarly in every place where we make a blessing on wine, because
>   of this enactment for wine in the course of a meal we do not say 
>   ברשות but instead  סברי because of the quoted reason.

The Mishna Berurah says

> (מו) כל מקום וכו' - ר"ל כשאחד מוציא חבירו כמו קידוש והבדלה וכה"ג.
>   ובחופה וברית מילה שאין נוהגין לומר סברי כלל הוא משום דרק במקום שצריך
>   נטילת רשות אומרים על היין סברי במקום רשות אבל בחופה ומילה שאין נוטלין
>   רשות אין לומר סברי כלל:
>
> In every place etc. This means that when one person wants to cover his
>   friend with a blessing like kiddush and havdoloh etc. And at a chupah
>   and a bris miloh where there is no custom to say  סברי at all it is
>   because only where it is necessary to ask permission that we say on
>   wine  סברי instead of  רשות whereas at a chupah and a bris miloh where
>   we do not ask permission, we do not say  סברי at all.

The MB says that at a chupah we do not ask permission to say the blessing on wine. Now Halachipedia quotes the Oruch HaShulchan to say that

> Regarding the cup under the chuppah, those reciting the brachos do not
>   need to drink from the cup, but the bride and groom should at least
>   taste from it.

So the one making the brocha on the wine under the chupa does so for the bride and groom. Why then does the MB say he should not say  סברי?

Comment: Probably because those two people have asked the person in question to be motzi them, and are already paying full attention.

Answer (score 2):

Mishnah Berurah explains in 174:47 that one says סברי before wine where one would normally be expected to say ברשות, i.e. asking the permission of those present to be the one to say the blessing on their behalves, where they themselves could have been the one to say the blessing.

This would not apply at a wedding. Even though the officiant is making the blessing on the wine on behalf of the couple who will drink from it, he does not need to ask their permission to do so (either because of his position as the local rabbi, or because the couple have asked him to officiate).

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Joel's answer, Sheva Brachot (the ones at the end of the meal; not the ones said at the chuppa.) also don't get *savri*.

By the logic stated in Joel K's answer, consider that the one making that bracha is the one who led the zimun. He already requested permission at the beginning of benching, and that, presumably, would include the bracha on the wine at the end of Sheva Brachot.

Comment: and how would it be at a normal non-sheva-brochos meal?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok It's the same idea. I get your point of your follow up question. The reason I mentioned *sheva brachot* is that many custom sdon't use a cup of wine at non-sheva brachot meals. Also, OP's question relates to weddings.